# GUI with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Getting started with GUI with Tkinter but it's not running

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
thelabel = Label(root, "hello")
thelabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guidemo1.py", line 4, in <module>
    thelabel = Label(root, "hello")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, 

in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2295, in __init__
    classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) for `Label` says that the second argument is a *list* not a string. You could skip this second positional argument and use the keyword argument `text`:

```
thelabel = Label(root, text = "hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
thelabel = Label(root, "hello")
```

You should have used the "text" argument for Labels

```
theLabel = Label(root, text="hello")
```

Comment: I think its an argument rather than parameter here.

Answer (score 0):

the `Label` is not done correctly, the code must be:

```
import tkinter

root = tk.Tk()
thelabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="hello")
thelabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

also, you can use `from tkinter import*` as well, i just do it like this, if you do so, also change the label to `Label(root, text="hello")` and root to just `Tk()`

Comment: Shouldnt it be `from tkinter import *`

Comment: there are other ways, from tkinter import * is an option, but i just feel comfortable doing this